# Showing $S \setminus S = \emptyset$ for any set $S$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Edit per the comment recieved: I have started self-learning the book Real Analysis with Economic Applications by Efe A. Ok. The first chapter is concerned with set theory which is a weakness for me. The exercise A2.b asks the reader to show $S \setminus S = \emptyset$ for any set $S$. I intuitively understand it but the math is very abstract for me.

My attempt:

Assume $x \in S\setminus S $

We know that $ S\setminus S \subseteq S$

Thus $x \in S$

But by definition of set difference we also have that  $ x \in S \wedge x \notin S \ $

Which is a contradiction, hence it must be the case that $ S \setminus S = \emptyset$

I seem to understand what I am doing but also am really confused...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have edited the question.

Comment: I would define it as $S \setminus S = \{ x : x \in S \wedge x \notin S \}$

Comment: I don't see any reason to be confused. You have proved the result correctly.

Comment: Alright then, I just thought my jump from the contradiction to the equality is very abrupt. Most similar proofs in set theory regarding equality seem to make use of $\subseteq$ twice to reach equality, hence my confusion.

Comment: We can show this even in plain text : The given set is the set of elements in $S$ not being in $S$. Obviously, there cannot be such an element, hence the set must be the empty set.